# How to add another domain (SOA) to my bind9 installation when domain has not been delegated yet. What are the delegation steps?

Tags: debian, dns, bind9

I have a bind9 installation on my Debian Wheezy install.
On this install I have a DNS-server which acts as the SOA for a domain, example1.com.
My name server is also on the same domain, example1.com (see excerpt from db1.example.com below). This has been achieved by glue records at my hosting provider).

Now I want to add another domain, example2.com to this bind9 installation, so that it is the master DNS-server for both domains.

I already have:

(from named.conf)

```
zone "example1.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example1.com";
};
```

(from db.example1.com)

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example1.com. root.example1.com. (
                      1         ; Serial
                 604800         ; Refresh
                  86400         ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                 604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example1.com.
```

Now, I tried to add another zone entry in named.conf and a file db.example2.com (corresponding to the db.example1.com). But that leads to bind failing to start.

- What is missing? Does the delegation (by ISP) of the domain example2.com have to be done before adding it to my DNS-server?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, is local to your machine. Unfortunately it's not possible to say what the problem is, since you don't show us the new (non-working) configuration or the error message you get when trying to load it.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, the delegation does not have to be done beforehand.

You can configure your nameserver to your will, and it is even best to do it before delegating to them some domains, as you can then test them and only later change the delegation in parent zone.

As for your specific problem, you will need to show your real files and names, and the error messages.